# How do you define an operator in prolog to make a list?

Tags: list, operators, prolog

I want to define an operator "++>" in a way so that typing "a ++> b" will make a list of [a,b].

I've written the following code, but it doesn't appear to do the job.

```
++>(X,Y) :-
 [X,Y].

:- op(500,xfy,++>).
```

Comment: There are really two issues here, defining operator "++>" as an infix notation, and arranging that the expression "a ++> b" would be "evaluated" as the term [a,b].  The first part of this is fairly standard Prolog as you seem to know from the mention of **op/3**.  Getting the machinery in place to "evaluate" terms involving the new operator is trickier.  For arithmetic functions SWI-Prolog has a directive that allows **is/2** to work with user-defined functions, but yours is not an arithmetic function.  I could show you how to define a new predicate **iz/2** that would "evaluate" ++> terms.

Comment: I had the occasion to go digging for SWI-Prolog's `arithmetic_function/1` directive, and I notice it has been [deprecated, perhaps dropped](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=arithmetic_function/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
:- op(500,xfy,++>).
++>(X,Y,[X,Y]).
```

And use it like

```
?- ++>(1,2,X).
X = [1, 2].
```

Actually, Prolog is not oriented calculations, so operators is just synonyms to the terms.
You want a term\3, where one element is list of two another. So, you can't use 2-placed operator in that case. Btw, you can't use **is** in this situation, because it used only in arithmetic cases.

Comment: There is no use in declaring an operator in your example. You declared a 2 arguments operator (++>/2) but defined a 3 arguments predicate (++>/3)

Comment: Right, then let's declare some 3place operator

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
++>((X,Y),Z) :-Z= [X,Y].

:- op(500,xfy,++>).
```

Answer (score 0):

`[a,b,c]` is just syntactic sugar for `'.'(a,'.'(b,'.'(c))))`. So you may define your operator just the same and write a conversion predicate:

```
:- op(500,xfy,'++>').

convert('++>'(A,B),[A|R]) :-
    convert(B,R).
convert(Any,[Any]).
```

Example:

```
| ?- X = 1++>2++>3, convert(X,Y).                                    
X = 1++>2++>3
Y = [1,2,3] ?
yes
```